# Craft 3 Setup: Testing Database Credentials Failed

Tags: craft3, setup

I receive the following error message: Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory and am not entirely too sure what I need to do to connect to this database.  I'm not sure if it's a MAMP error or a Craft setup error as well.

```
// ♥ ~/development/craft3local/install/craft setup
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: mysql
Database server name or IP address: [localhost] localhost
Database port: [3306] 8889
Database username: [root] root
Database password: 
Database name: craft3local
Database table prefix: 
Testing database credentials... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I am using MAMP, not the Pro version.  My port is 8889 confirmed from the start page info and checking the ports section of the setup. I have also tried creating a different user for the database and it also did not work.

Many thanks for any assistance.